# Parallels cant access SSD partitions

Tags: windows, bootcamp, partition, parallels-desktop

I have 4 partitions

1. MAC
2. Shared 1 exFAT
3. Windows
4. Shared 2 exFAT

I can see the partitions when Windows natively but when I am booting Windows through Parallels I cant access any other partitions but Windows

[image]

Is there any ways I can fix that?

Was trying this solution http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?88709-Creating-custom-Boot-Camp-configurations-in-Parallels-Desktop-4 but not working in the **Parrallels 9**

Comment: Virtual machines don't usually allow access to all local files by default. You have to specifically enable sharing. See lauhub's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to **Configure>Hardware>Hard Disk 1** and checked all partitions, Partition 2 and 4  weren't checked by default

[image]

So now my Partitions looking like that:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In VM configuration, did you check the Options>Sharing settings are OK ?

SmartMount should be checked.

And verify that all the volumes are mounted by MacOS.

Comment: All sharing where OK. Couldn't wee SmartMount option but I find out how to mount missed partitions.